# How to take a cisco output and put it into a dictionary

Tags: variables, ansible, output, allocation

On a Cisco ASA, I'm running the command "show run interface".  I would like to take that output and put it into a dictionary, where then I can reference the values for IP Address and Interface Name.

I would normally use REST, however our model doesn't have REST support.  The Ansible Module is too limited in its capabilities to do this either.  So I'm unsure where to even start on this one.

Sample output:

```
interface Ethernet1/1
 vlan 555
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet1/2
 vlan 777
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Please add the desired dictionary in the question that you would want based on the provided command output.

Comment: See [Parsing semi-structured text with Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/cli_parsing.html#parsing-semi-structured-text-with-ansible) and [pyats_parser](https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/ansible-pyats) in particular.

Comment: Ansible can be quite limited. I use python and NTC templates.

Answer (score 1):

Given the *output*

```yaml
  output: |-
    interface Ethernet1/1
     vlan 555
     nameif inside
     security-level 100
     ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
    !
    interface Ethernet1/2
     vlan 777
     nameif outside
     security-level 0
     ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.0
    !
    interface Ethernet1/3
     vlan 333
     nameif outside
     security-level 0
     ip address 3.3.3.3 255.255.255.0
```

---

Use [*native parsing engine*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/cli_parsing.html#parsing-with-the-native-parsing-engine). Create a template

```yaml
shell> cat templates/nxos_show_run_interface.yaml
---
- example: 'interface Ethernet1/1'
  getval: 'interface (?P<name>\S+)'
  result:
    "{{ name }}":
      name: "{{ name }}"
  shared: true
- example: ' vlan 555'
  getval: ' vlan (?P<vlan>\S+)'
  result:
    "{{ name }}":
      name: "{{ name }}"
      vlan: "{{ vlan }}"
- example: ' nameif inside'
  getval: ' nameif (?P<nameif>\S+)'
  result:
    "{{ name }}":
      name: "{{ name }}"
      nameif: "{{ nameif }}"
- example: ' security-level 0'
  getval: ' security-level (?P<security_level>\S+)'
  result:
    "{{ name }}":
      name: "{{ name }}"
      security-level: "{{ security_level }}"
- example: ' ip address 3.3.3.3 255.255.255.0'
  getval: ' ip address (?P<ip_address>\S+)'
  result:
    "{{ name }}":
      name: "{{ name }}"
      ip_address: "{{ ip_address }}"
```

The task below

```yaml
    - ansible.utils.cli_parse:
        text: "{{ output }}"
        parser:
          name: ansible.netcommon.native
          template_path: templates/nxos_show_run_interface.yaml
      register: parser_output
```

gives

```yaml
  parser_output.parsed:
    Ethernet1/1:
      ip_address: 1.1.1.1
      name: Ethernet1/1
      nameif: inside
      security-level: 100
      vlan: 555
    Ethernet1/2:
      ip_address: 2.2.2.2
      name: Ethernet1/2
      nameif: outside
      security-level: 0
      vlan: 777
    Ethernet1/3:
      ip_address: 3.3.3.3
      name: Ethernet1/3
      nameif: outside
      security-level: 0
      vlan: 333
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    output: |-
      interface Ethernet1/1
       vlan 555
       nameif inside
       security-level 100
       ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
      !
      interface Ethernet1/2
       vlan 777
       nameif outside
       security-level 0
       ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.0
      !
      interface Ethernet1/3
       vlan 333
       nameif outside
       security-level 0
       ip address 3.3.3.3 255.255.255.0

  tasks:
    - ansible.utils.cli_parse:
        text: "{{ output }}"
        parser:
          name: ansible.netcommon.native
          template_path: templates/nxos_show_run_interface.yaml
      register: parser_output
    - debug:
        var: parser_output.parsed
```

- Try to parse the output in the same task when running on a Cisco ASA

```yaml
    - ansible.utils.cli_parse:
        command: show run interface
        parser:
          name: ansible.netcommon.native
        set_fact: interfaces
```

should give the same result

```yaml
  interfaces:
    Ethernet1/1:
      ip_address: 1.1.1.1
      name: Ethernet1/1
      nameif: inside
      security-level: 100
      vlan: 555
    Ethernet1/2:
      ip_address: 2.2.2.2
      name: Ethernet1/2
      nameif: outside
      security-level: 0
      vlan: 777
    Ethernet1/3:
      ip_address: 3.3.3.3
      name: Ethernet1/3
      nameif: outside
      security-level: 0
      vlan: 333
```